# How to build a Graph from a Vector of Structs

Tags: rust

I've got a JSON data structure that I've mapped to a Rust struct using Serde. Each entry is a Node with some properties and an attribute called `depends_on` that contains a list of the parent node names (strings).

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct NodeDeps {
    pub nodes: Vec<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Node {
    pub unique_id: String,
    pub depends_on: Option<NodeDeps>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Manifest {
    pub nodes: HashMap<String, Node>,
}
```

I want to map this to a PetGraph structure but I can't figure out how to make the edges since I can only access the graph nodes via index.

This is what I have so far:

```
    let mut graph = Graph::<&Node, ()>::new();

    for (_, node) in mfst.nodes.iter() {
        graph.add_node(node);
    }

    for node_ix in graph.node_indices() {
        if let Some(ref deps) = graph[node_ix].depends_on {
            for dep in deps.nodes.iter() {
                for inner_ix in graph.node_indices() {
                    if graph[inner_ix].unique_id.as_str() == dep {
                        graph.update_edge(inner_ix, node_ix, ());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    println!("{:?}", &graph);
}
```

Update:
This seems better, but still requires an intermediate data structure:

```
    let mut node_set: HashMap<&str, NodeIndex> = HashMap::new();
    for (counter, (node_id, node)) in mfst.nodes.iter().enumerate() {
        graph.add_node(node);
        node_set.insert(node_id, NodeIndex::new(counter));
    }

    for (node_id, node) in mfst.nodes.iter() {
        if let Some(ref deps) = node.depends_on {
            for dep in deps.nodes.iter() {
                graph.update_edge(
                    *node_set.get(dep.as_str()).unwrap(),
                    *node_set.get(node_id.as_str()).unwrap(),
                    (),
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

These work, but seems very wasteful and complex.
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I think the latter solution is the best you can get (but you can build the graph and hashmap with `with_capacity()`) for slightly faster execution).